# How can I make the CSS 'min-height' property ineffective?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.one, .two {
  border:1px solid;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.two {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">something1</div><br>
<div class="two">something2</div>
```

All I'm trying to do is deactivate `min-height` property for `.two`. I can do the same thing by using `auto` for `height`. Like this: `.two{height:auto}`. But how can I do that for `min-height` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [relevant W3.org documentation on the `min-height` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights), the initial value is `0`.

Therefore, if you want to override the `min-height` property on that element and set it back to its initial value, you would use:

```
.two {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

Of course you could also use the [`initial` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) (i.e, `min-height: initial`), however that isn't supported across all browsers. See [this relevant caniuse page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-value) for a reference on the current browser support of the `initial` property.

Answer (score 1):

set `min-height: initial;` that would let you to `min-height: 0`

```css
.one,
.two {
  border: 1px solid;
  min-height: 300px;
}
.two {
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">something1</div>
<br>
<div class="two">something2</div>
```

Comment: @stack - Keep in mind that the `initial` value isn't supported in all browsers. See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-value

Comment: when @JoshCrozier means all browsers he means IE11 and below ;), so the usual

Comment: @dippas - Haha... and Opera mobile and IE mobile  :) I am glad Edge supports it. Microsoft is finally building a decent web browser.